# FlowPlayer: Display video description from database when user clicks that playlist item

Tags: flash, flowplayer

I have setup FlowPlayer and a playlist using the jquery plugin. The items on the playlist are generated in a php while loop as the file names come from a database.

I want to grab the video 'description' from the database and display it in a div, but only when the user clicks that playlist item. I have tried using the onStart event but i'm not sure how to get this working with the database.

Anyone have any experience with this?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easiest if you put the description into hidden divs during the filename loop, and then have the onStart event `$(divname).show()` the div corresponding to the playlist entry.

It would be easier to help you if you posted the code you have so far.